# Adding Kotlin extension methods to a pure Java library

Tags: java, kotlin, extension-methods

I am developing a pure Java library and want to add some Kotlin specific extension methods.
Is there a way to add these extension methods to the already existing pure Java JAR or am I forced to create a new Kotlin specific module that has to be published separately? If so, will they be visible to Java users, in what way?

I don't mind using the Kotlin compiler to compile my library if this avoids the release of separate JARs just for literally 3 lines of code.

I need these extension methods to work around type-inference / method reference resolution differences between Java and Kotlin.

Comment: It's certainly possible to include both Kotlin classes (compiled with the Kotlin compiler) and Java class (compiled with the Java compiler) in the same project, and compiled into the same jar.  Both Maven and Gradle support this (or you could roll your own, of course).

Comment: Kotlin APIs are visible to Java as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html), but there are ways to prevent them from being visible if you so desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods are compiled to static Java methods, for example from `app.kt` into the class `AppKt`, i.e. they are available to Java as well using `AppKt.method()`, [as explained in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions).

Both your Java code and Kotlin code compile to Java Bytecode class files and can go into the same jar, i.e., no need to ship multiple jars. My personal build system of choice for building Kotlin/Java code is Gradle, but this is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to setup my Maven process accordingly.

Comment: @roookeee Glad I could help. If this answer helped I, I would appreciate it if you could accept it. :)